# SQL Server 2008 R2 Memory Utilization

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, memory

I am facing below issue with my Server. Does this directly indicate that I have to increase my RAM immediately?

Current Setting SQL Server memory values, out of total physical RAM of 128GB:

- Min Server Memory - 0
- Max Server Memory - 120 GB

I have mentioned the perfmon counters too below. Kindy advise.

We are getting this alert at least every 2 days alternatively.

> SQL Server:Buffer Manager Page writes/sec has exceeded the threshold
>   of 90

[image]

- Perfmon counter Values :

[image]

[image]

Comment: That's a first. Never seen Buffer cache hit ratio above 100%. Anyway, what are the actual values set for MIN memory and MAX memory on the SQL Instance and how much memory does the server have?

Comment: Why do you keep asking the same question in different ways over different days?

Comment: Yes I agree @Randolph West but I am bit confused over the sentence -- The system is experiencing excessive paging. So I want to be more clear whether I need to increase RAM or not.

Comment: @hot2use,I just edited my question.

Comment: What processes are running against your database every 2 days?

Comment: Majorly FULL Backup job runs the time we get this alerts.DBs which are close to 1.2 TB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Majorly FULL Backup job runs the time we get this alerts.DBs which are close to 1.2 TB

Memory allocated to SQL Server is 120 G and backup running is for 1.2TB + database and in such scenario of course a high page write would be done. IF this message is only coming when backup is running you might  ignore it. In your [exact previous thread](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/155265/sql-serverbuffer-manager-page-reads-write-sec-has-exceeded-the-threshold/155279#155279), I asked you to ignore it as well.

I also asked you to collect perfmon counter values using performance data collector set and this is much needed because to answer your question whether the alert actually should be considered or can be ignored depends on that. You have to have performance/system benchmark to which you can compare other results.

**NOTE:** Seeing the database size I can say with confidence that adding more RAM would always help. Ideally if you take my advise RAM allocated to SQL Server should be 1/3rd of total database size. RAM's are cheaper those days instead of wasting too much effort in solving an alert I suggest you to go ahead and add more RAM, that would really be worth.

If you want me to analyze the data collector result personally my website has my mail id send me the details I can help you with the analysis.